# How to search for obtaining the "best" result

Tags: sql, full-text-search

suppose someone enter this search (on an form):

```
Nicole Kidman films
```

Which SQL i can use to find "the best" results ?

I suppose something like this :

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE ( Field='%Nicole Kidman Films%' OR Field='%Nicole%' OR Field='%Kidman%' OR Field='%Films%' )
```

My question is how to get most relevant result ? 
Thank you very much!

Comment: Tell me what "best" and "most relevant" mean and how to calculate them and I will give you an answer.

Comment: you're right.. but i absolutely don't know the argument..

Comment: You're headed towards some pretty deep waters, make sure your life vest is working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**Full-Text Search**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-natural-language.html):

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE MATCH(Field) AGAINST('Nicole Kidman Films')
```

This query will return rows in order of relevancy, as defined by the full-text search algorithm.

*Note: This is for MySQL, other DBMS have similar functionality.*

Comment: T H A N K Y O U   V E R Y   M U C H ... i absolutely didn't know this features ! Wonderful ..

Answer (score 2):

What you're looking for is often called a "full text search" or a "natural language search". Unfortunately it's not standard SQL. Here's a tutorial on how to do it in mysql: http://devzone.zend.com/article/1304

You should be able to find examples for other database engines.

Answer (score 0):

In SQL, the equals sign doesn't support wildcards in it - your query should really be:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM myTable 
 WHERE Field LIKE '%Nicole Kidman Films%' 
    OR Field LIKE '%Nicole%' 
    OR Field LIKE '%Kidman%' 
    OR Field LIKE '%Films%'
```

But wildcarding the left side won't use an index, if one exists.

A better approach is to use Full Text Searching, which most databases provide natively but there are 3rd party vendors like Sphinx.  Each has it's own algorithm to assign a rank/score based on the criteria searched on in order to display what the algorithm deems most relevant.